# how to predict more multiple values in azure ml?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am creating Azure ML experienment to predict multiple values. but in azure ml we can not train a model to predict multiple values. my question is how to bring multiple trained models in single experienment and create webout put that gives me multiple prediction.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to manually save the trained models (right click the module output and save to your workspace) from your training experiment and then manually create the predictive experiment unlike what is done in this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/walkthrough-5-publish-web-service
Regards,
Jaya